# Confused by all the promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following factory.  It also has a function that returns an array of allowed times (calculation based on the info returned by the call).  I want to make this info available in the template, how do I do so in the controller?

```
.factory('Company', function($resource) {
  var myCompany = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/companies').get();

  return {
    allowed_times: function(){
      myCompany.$promise.then(function(data, status){
        var list = new Array();
        list[list.length] = moment().set('hour', data.settings.work_time_start).set('minute', 0).set('second', 0);
        endTime = moment().set('hour', data.settings.work_time_end).set('minute', 0).set('second', 0);
        var currentTime = moment().set('hour', data.settings.work_time_start).set('minute', 0).set('second', 0);
        while (list[list.length - 1] < endTime)
        {
          list[list.length] = moment(list[list.length - 1]).add(data.settings.time_rounding, 'm');
        };
        return list;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

I already tried different approaches, this is the latest but gives an error message (Cannot read property 'then' of undefined).

```
Company.allowed_times().then(function(data) {
        $scope.allowed_times = data
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to chain `then` method to result of `Company.allowed_times()` call, `allowed_times` must return a promise object. Right not it returns `undefined`. The fix is simple, you just need to return `myCompany.$promise.then(function() {...})`:

```
allowed_times: function () {
    return myCompany.$promise.then(function (data, status) {
        // ... unchanged
        return list;
    });
}
```

One thing: if you use `then` method, remember to return from it, it will become new promise passed to the next `then` call.

Comment: That's pretty cool, wasn't aware of "*will become new promise passed to the next then call*".

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Yep, this is one of the coolest things about promises which allows one `then` block to modify or return completely new promise to be handed to the next handler.

Comment: Thanks! So simple, yet this had me searching for over an hour. I upvoted the answer of Patrick as well which was practically the same.

Answer (score 3):

No need to create an extra deferred and promise (see the `Forgotten Promise` in [promise anti-patterns](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/))

Just return the promise from the resource call:

```
.factory('Company', function($resource) {
  var myCompany = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/companies').get();

  return {
    allowed_times: function(){
      //return the promise created by this call
      return myCompany.$promise.then(function(data, status){
         var list = [];

         //populate list with data...

         return list;
      });
    }
  }
});
```